# Solving $x^2 - 16 > 0$ for $x$

Tags: inequality, quadratics

This may be a very simple question, but I can't figure out the correct reason behind it.

> If $x^2 - 16 >0$, which of the following must be true?
>
> a. $4 < x$
>
> b. $-4 > x > 4$
>
> c. $-4 > x < 4$
>
> d. $-4 < x < 4$

I know the [answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%20-%2016%20%3E0) but I didn't get how they figured out the direction.

Comment: I suppose that by $-4 > x > 4$ they mean $\{x : x < -4 \text{ or } x > 4\}$ (otherwise the correct answer is none of the above) but that is really bad notation. $-4 > x > 4$ means that $x$ is greater than $4$ **and** less than $-4$, which holds for no $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your inequality $$x^2-16 > 0$$ factors as $$(x-4)(x+4) > 0.$$  Since the product of $(x-4)$ and $(x+4)$ is positive, they must have the same sign.

- Suppose $x-4$ and $x+4$ are both positive.  But $x+4$ is bigger than $x-4$, so it is enough for $x-4$ to be positive; if it is, then the other one will be too.  $x-4$ is positive whenever $x>4$.
- Or both  $x-4$ and $x+4$  could be negative.  But $x+4$ is bigger than $x-4$, so if $x+4$ is negative, $x-4$ is also.  And $x+4$ is negative whenever $x<-4$.

So the solution is that either $x<-4$ or $x>4$.

Looking at the multiple-choice, I have no idea which to choose; they all seem wrong.
Whoever wrote the question should get a kick in the pants for writing the absurd “$-4 > x < 4$” and the patently false “$-4 > x > 4$”.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(-4)^2=4^2=16,$ and for $x^2-16>0$ to be true, $x$ has to be strictly greater than $4$ and strictly less than $-4,$ then from this I think you can tell which answer must be correct

Comment: Oh, so this inequality doesnt hold for x > -4. Got it! Thanks!

Comment: Technically it doesn't hold for $-4\le x\le 4$

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to consider a factored form of the inequality:

$(x-4)(x+4)>0$

Now, for this to be positive, both factors have to share the same sign and so one could look at this as 2 cases:

1) $x-4>0$ and $x+4>0$ which would imply $x>4$

2) $x-4<0$ and $x+4<0$ which would imply $x<-4$

Then, one just combines these cases to get the proper answer.